# How do i combine user input change text method and an if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input

I want to combine these two blocks in the script. I want it so that when you type river into the text box i can give a good job statement or post a link.
I don't know what to use as the variable in the second statement. Which is the if statement.

```
var userInput.value=river;
if(userInput.value)=="river"){
document.write("hey");
}
<br/>
function changeText2(){
var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput').value;
document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML=userInput;
}


</script>
<p>What has a mouth but can't chew?<b id='boldStuff2'>???</b></p>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter Answer Here'/>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Answer'/>



</head>
</html>
```

Comment: `var userInput.value=river;` This makes my head spin

Answer (score 1):

First three lines of that code are not only wrong logically, they are unnecessary as well. Try a simple version

```
<script>
function changeText2(){
var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput').value;

if(userInput.toLowerCase()=="river")
{
alert("Good Job");
}

document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML=userInput;
}


</script>
<p>What has a mouth but can't chew?<b id='boldStuff2'>???</b></p>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter Answer Here'/>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Answer'/>



</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks i am really new and appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

se this function in your JScript code

```
   function changeText2(){
     var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput').value;
     if(userInput=="river")
     {
      document.write("");
     }
     document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML=userInput;
   }
```